# Views contextual filter not working for Pathauto path

Tags: views

Im using Pathauto so set aliases for taxonomy terms.

So this:
/taxonomy/term/1

Is the same as this:
/custom-term-url

Im using Drupals default Taxonomy term View to control the layout of the term page. This works fine for both of the paths.

Ive created an additional page in this view with a path of /taxonomy/term/%/something and an additional filter so show different results.

When I go to this page everything works perfectly:
/taxonomy/term/1/something

However this returns a page not found: 
/custom-term-url/something

How can I get my View working with the Pathauto URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the [Sub-path URL Aliases](https://www.drupal.org/project/subpathauto) module, which should do exactly what you're after.

Comment: You've got the wrong URL but the module does what I need: https://www.drupal.org/project/subpathauto

Comment: Sorry about that, I've corrected it for anyone else reading

Answer (score 0):

Install [Global Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/globalredirect) module, this module create a unique form of all of the aliases. I am not able to test this solution of your problem But I guess it may solve the problem.

Comment: Ive installed the module. If I go to /taxonomy/term/1 I get redirected to /custom-term-url. However /taxonomy/term/1/something does not get redirect. I cant see a way in Pathauto to set a pattern for this page.

Comment: wildcards are not registered, that's why you are not redirected